# How to hide scrollbar from UI but keeps spacing?

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'd like to hide the scrollbar of a  but keep the scrollbar space intact such that toggling between hide and show doesn't move the layout of UI.

I have tried:

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar {
visibility: none;
}
```

but doesn't work.

I hope the above information is sufficient but I am willing to provide more when requested. All help is appreciated.